# How to remove multiple elements from a list without using del

Tags: python

How do you remove specified ranges from a string?

The function should take a string and lists of indices, and returns a new string
with the characters between those indices deleted.

Arguments:

```
my_str (str): The string to be modified.
ranges (list): A list of [start, end] indices.
```

Assume that both start and end are valid indices `(ie. between 0 and len(my_str), inclusive)`, and that `start <= end`. Assume that the ranges are sorted from earliest to latest `(ie. [0, 10] will come before [15, 20])`, and that the ranges will not overlap.

I have no idea how to start, the point is to not use the `del` statement

example:

```
word = "white laptop"
indices = [9, 11]
print(remove_range(word, indices)

>>> white lap
```

Comment: Please give more context, especially how much you now understand about Python strings. For example, do you understand Python's slice notation? Concatenation?

Comment: Use slicing `word[:indices[0]] + word[indices[1]+1:]`

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create a function, you could pass the indices and use those to slice the string you pass into the function, also the indices for desired result would be `9, 12`

```
def remove_indices(s, indices):
    return s[:indices[0]] + s[indices[1]:]

s = 'white laptop'
indices = [9, 12]

print(remove_indices(s, indices))
```

> ```
> white lap
> ```

Comment: can simply put: s=s[:indices[0]]+s[indices[1]:]. This should do. But if function necessary.... well written, the python way.

Comment: @Eswar yep working off OPs request but in reality agree, no need for function definition

Answer (score 0):

As RafaelC said use slicing:

```
word=word[:indices[0]] + word[indices[1]+1:]
```

Or another slicing way is:

```
word=word.replace(word[indices[0]:indices[1]+1],'')
```

Or another way is:

```
word=word.replace(word[slice(*indices)],'')[:-1]
```

Now:

```
print(word)
```

For all solutions reproduce:

```
white lap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join([w for i, w in enumerate(word) if i not in indices])

 'white lapo'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension.

```
word = "white laptop"
indices = [9, 11]
output = ''
output = [word[index] for index in range(0, len(word)) if (index < indices[0] or index > indices[1])]
output = ''.join(map(str, output))
print(output )
```

This outputs '*white lap*', as specified.